# Tried to restore postgres database but "no such file or directory" is shown

Tags: postgresql

I am just very new to PostgresSQL.I would like to restore backup database by type the following command `psql -d library < joins.sql`,but the return result will always be`zsh: no such file or directory: joins.sql`.I have searched for google and stackoverflow,but it seems there is no similar situation as what I had,which make me very confused.
I am wondering maybe is the path of the file and and the postgres are not the same.I also tried to check the path,but didn't get some idea.
Does anyone have met this issue,and know what is the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: It looks like `joins.sql` isn't in the current working directory when you type the `psql` command. Where did you put the `joins.sql` file? Try using the full path, e.g. `psql -d library < /home/jlin/joins.sql`

Comment: You are right! After I typed the full path it works.Thanks very much for your helping.